# How to dynamically add attribute to a group of already-built objects in Javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

If I use a constructor function build a lot of objects, later I realize I need to add new attribute to them, I wonder how should I design the constructor function that let its instance object can automatically inherit newly added attribute while being able to override that value without affect other object.

**My original user requirement is like:**

Janet is working on a feature to save settings for a game, and would like these settings to be stored in the cloud so they can also be managed via a separate web interface. The game settings data will only consist of key/value pairs (KVPs), where keys can be arbitrary strings (within character set [a-z0-9.]) and values can only be simple primitive types (string, number, boolean, and null). Additionally, she would like the ability to **organize settings into logical groups** (e.g. “difficulty”) and create variations of each group **without having to duplicate data** (e.g. “easy”, “hard”). For instance, a key of “maxEnemyCount” in the “difficulty” group would **automatically be inherited by** sub-groups “easy” and “hard”, and could be optionally overridden in each.

This is from someone else, if there is any unclear requirement to you, just use your own judgement to solve it.

I guess I must misunderstand this requirement, so please just post your solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: Given that you added the prototype tag, it seems you already know about prototypes. What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: @FelixKling I update my question, could you take a look?

Comment: Please post your solution so far.  StackOverflow is for improving and fixing *existing solutions*.  StackOverflow is not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is done via `prototype` in JavaScript.

```
Foo = function(){};
var foo1 = new Foo();
var foo2 = new Foo();
foo2.newAttribute = "world";
Foo.prototype.newAttribute = "hello";
console.log(foo1.newAttribute); // "hello"
console.log(foo2.newAttribute); // "world"
```

Comment: Down-voter: I always appreciate feedback in the form of a comment.

Comment: Thanks, I update my question, could you take a look?

Comment: @Kuan: Your update does nothing to clarify the question. I have no idea how your original question relates to the requirements you posted. Can you clarify what specific programming problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry,  The updated part is my question. Forget what I post before.

Comment: @Kuan: The updated part is not a question at all--it is a set of requirements. The purpose of StackOverflow is to help you overcome specific problems that you run into. Often someone else in the community can take 5 minutes to help you through a problem that would have taken you hours to overcome on your own. But we're not going to spend hours of our own time doing your work for you.

Comment: U r right, I will try to write  some lines of code see what I can do and figure out what question should ask. Thanks for help.